# C# ExecuteReaderAsync Sporadic Issue

Tags: ado.net, sql-server-2017

I have a method that is getting a list of users. There is a store procedure that is expected either a username or null. It returns one or more users based on the parameter. It works fine most of the time, but I notice there are times it does not return any result even though I am passing the same exact parameter. I put a break point in the Execute Reader Async, and the line immediately following it. When the issue occurs, it reaches the first break point but not the second one. It does not throw an exception or prevent me from making another call. I can make the next call, and it will return the result as expected. I would appreciate some suggestions as to what may cause this issue?

```
 public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers(string username, int accountType = 1)
    {
        List<User> users = null;
      
        parameters = new List<SqlParameter>{
                    new SqlParameter{
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    ParameterName = "@userName",
                    Value = username.NotEmpty() ? username : (object) DBNull.Value
                 },
                 new SqlParameter{
                    DbType = DbType.Int32,
                    ParameterName = "@accountType",
                    Value = accountType
                 }
            };

        try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetUsers", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlDataReader dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()
                        if (dr.HasRecord())
                        {
                            while (await dr.ReadAsync())
                            {
                                User user = new User();
                                user.FirstName = dr["firstName"].ToString();
                                user.LastName = dr["lastName"].ToString();
                                user.DateRegister = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateRegister"].ToString());
                                user.Active = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Active"].ToString());
                                if(users == null)
                                {
                                    users = new List<User>();
                                }
                                users.Add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Util.LogError(ex.ToString());
                users = null;
            }
        return users;

    }
```

**Update:**

Yes, the error is being logged. Also, I added a breakpoint in the catch statement in case an error is thrown.

**Here is the query that is used to create that store procedure:**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('spGetUsers') AND TYPE IN (N'PC', N'P'))
DROP PROCEDURE spGetUsers
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetUsers
 @userName nvarchar(50),
@accountType int = 1
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT U.firstName, U.lastName, U.DateRegister, A.Active
 FROM [User] U
 inner join UserAccount UA
 on U.Id = UA.userid
 inner join Account A
 on A.Id = UA.accountId
 WHERE U.Id > 0
 AND UA.Id > 0
 AND A.Id > 0
 AND UA.AccountType IN (@accountType )
 and (A.UserName in (@userName) or @userName IS NULL)
END
```

**Extension Method to check if SQL DataReader has record**

```
   public static bool HasRecord(this System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr)
        {
            if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: You haven't described any specific problem. It's quite possible there *aren't* any data to return or that the query is written in a way it returns different results even for the same parameter and data. The posted code has some issues that should raise compiler warnings at least - the exception is simply ignored,  while `Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray())` should simply be `Parameters.AddRange(parameters)`. And `either a username or null` is a *very* strong smell suggesting the stored procedure is using a `catch-all` query that can lead to bad performance

Comment: It's impossible to guess what may be happening without the stored procedure code. The C# code will swallow any errors so there's no way to know if the code throws

Comment: Do you log the exception? If not why not? If so please post all the details of that exception. In the code shown the exception is "swallowed" which means it is not reported and the code is allowed to continue execution as if nothing happened at all. In most situations this is bad practice (including this one). If you can't handle the exception than you need to not catch it or rethrow it using `throw;`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I would expect it to at least reach the line of code that is checking if there is a record. It never reaches that line of code or the catch statement.

Comment: @JosianeFerice that `UA.AccountType IN (@accountType )` is equivalent to `UA.AccountType =@accountType`. `IN` won't convert a string into a list of values. You haven't explained which line is reached and which isn't either. The code may be doing what you told it to, or throwing because a string was passed for `accountType` and that `catch` simply hid the problem

Comment: @igor yes, I am logging the exception and set the list of users to  null. However, there is no exception in this case. It never reaches the break point inside the catch statement.

Comment: @JosianeFerice the code you posted doesn't log anything. It's not complete either - where are the parameters?. The query has two logic bugs (the use of `IN` instead of `=`) and one performance bug (the catch-all query). Have you tried running the stored procedure with the same values you used in your code?

Comment: It reaches this line of code, SqlDataReader dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();. Once it reaches the break point on this line of code, I press F10 to continue. It never reaches the next line of code. I have SQL Profiler running for the past hour, and I am trying to see if I can get it to happen again.

Comment: It could be not related to sql at all but to how you are using Async/Await. When this is inconsistently used in a call stack the result can often be a deadlock. How is this being called? Are you mixing async/await with `.Result` somewhere else in your call stack? Example: `var users = yourService.GetUsers(p1, p2).Result;`

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure out this issue. In the end, I removed the async/await, and I have not seen that issue again.